# How to add total for the AlphaNumeric Field by triming the Alphabets using ASPxSummaryItem in DevExpress?

Tags: devexpress

My Column Having Value Like 1000EUR, 2000INR, 3000USD.I want to show the sum of Amount at footer of the gridview.

How Should i Calculate this total amount at the bottom of the column?

Any way to remove the Alphabets and Summ the Amount? In Usual ASPxSummaryItem Its Calculating as 0.

My Code:

```
<dxwgv:ASPxSummaryItem FieldName="CommissionAmount" SummaryType="Sum" DisplayFormat="Total Commission Amount = {0} " />
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the sum supposed to be? obviously not 6000.
The summary type you're using should be custom.

```
<dxwgv:ASPxSummaryItem FieldName="CommissionAmount"  SummaryType="Custom" DisplayFormat="Total Commission Amount = {0} " />
```

Then, add event handler for `ASPxGridView1_CustomSummaryCalculate` and add the code behind to do the conversion and summing such:

```
protected void ASPxGridView1_CustomSummaryCalculate(object sender, DevExpress.Data.CustomSummaryEventArgs e) 
{
    e.TotalValue = 1000 + 2000 * USD2EUR + 300 * INR2EUR;
}
```